# jQuery datepicker with extra data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, each

I would like to use a datepicker with extra data under the days for a car rent company. For example the car is not available on the 3 Nov, so I would like to show the 'not available' text under the number 3 in the datepicker.

My idea is to create a javascript array from the database and with `each` I try to modify the cols with `text`.

What do you think about it? Do you know alternative method or a jquery plugin what does same?

Comment: why don't you just disable that date.....

Comment: i think may be u need this http://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: @Sandeeproop thank you, it looks promising